# missing field in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have a `lookup field` that does not show up in the `Define Workflow Lookup`.

I can see it in InfoPath form but it is not showing up in the drop down in Sharepoint Designer to create a workflow.

I was planning to use this field as one of the conditions in the workflow.[image] 
See below screenshot:

Comment: sorry its not a calculated field but instead a lookup field

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the field to a workflow variable first and then use it in your condition.

Comment: Yeah thats what im planning to do. But then i cant even see the list column in the current item dropdown...

Comment: it seems to happen on lookup fields only...I tried in SP 2007 version and it works. I wonder what's causing it not to show.

Comment: Which version of Designer are you using?

Comment: SPD 2013 with Sharepoint Online

Comment: Check its not a hidden column in the content type or list, my Lookup columns are all available in SPD2013 using SPOnline